# For some reason I cannot get text from html

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping, bots

The code works until I try .text and it gives me the error "list' object has no attribute 'text". When I use .text with a single element from the same list it works perfectly fine. I also cant get text for href link. Any ideas?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
import requests
from selenium import webdriver

headers={

'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) 
 Chrome/72.0.3626.121 Safari/537.36'
 }


 base_url=('https://waxpeer.com/')
 driver=webdriver.Chrome()
 driver.get("https://waxpeer.com/")
 time.sleep(10)
 #driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="container"]/div[1]/div[1]/a').click()

 time.sleep(10)
 html=driver.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div/div/main/section/div[2]/div/div/div/a')
 print(html)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 issues...

There is no `text` associated with those xPaths.  I am assuming you want to print the URL for each item?

Also, you can't access it directly from a List.  You need to iterate over it.

```
html = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='lpd_div']/a")

for item in html:
    print(item.get_attribute("href"))


https://waxpeer.com/sport-gloves-vice-field-tested/item/21642893513
https://waxpeer.com/karambit-gamma-doppler-factory-new/item/21733106690
https://waxpeer.com/karambit-gamma-doppler-factory-new/item/21733106719
...
```

Note that I shortened your `xPath` to a more manageable one to work with

If you want to print the item description instead, use this...

```
html = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='lpd_div']/div[2]/p")
for item in html:
    print(item.text)

★ Sport Gloves
Field-Tested
★ Karambit
...
```

Comment: I actually need both but was not doing too bad with the first part. Thank you so much, this helps a ton